# The rich man and the 1000 casks of wine

Tags: puzzle, word-problem

I recently came across an interesting logic puzzle during a challenge at a programming competition. Neither of the people on the two-person team completing that challenge could figure out an answer that worked in every scenario, and neither could the other people on the school team.

The problem was described as follows:

> You are a rich and unscrupulous man who owns ten slaves. You are hosting a large dinner party in six hours at which you intend to serve one thousand casks of wine.
>
> Unfortunately, exactly one of the casks is poisoned. You know the poison takes effect between 30 minutes and five hours after ingestion, varying from person to person.
>
> You decide to use your slaves to figure out which cask contains the poison before the dinner party.
>
> Working under the assumptions that you cannot cancel the dinner party, and that there's no limit on how much wine a slave can drink, propose a way to figure out which single cask is poisoned before the dinner part begins.

The most obvious solution was to use a divide-and-conquer algorithm: assign 100 casks to each of the 10 slaves, then assign the 9 remaining healthy/living slaves to the 100  casks that incapacitated a slave, and repeat.

While this approach works assuming the poison acts in 30 minutes (or an otherwise short period of time), it fails assuming anything near the worst-case time of 5 hours.

Is there an approach which can be taken to determine which cask contains the poisoned wine within the 6 hours before the dinner party?

Comment: Isn't there some way to rephrase this problem so that (a) it is less distasteful (say, by having a solution that does not require the murder of ten powerless humans) and (b) the solution makes some sense (say, by not requiring anyone to notionally consume 500 glasses of wine in one hour)?  The former might be tolerable if the problem made sense with the given phrasing, but here the window dressing does not even tell a reasonable story.

Comment: @MJD What does it matter? I for one find the political incorrectness here rather funny.

Comment: @MJD I tried to transcribe the problem so that it's as close to the original statement as possible. The problem only really works when you use humans because (most likely) a sensor or electronic wine tester wouldn't need a 30min-5h delay to detect poison. If others share your concern I'll revise the question and reword it.

Comment: @Lovsovs It has nothing to do with political correctness.  As I have already pointed out, the unnecessary story setting interferes with the mathematics, since it makes absurd what could in a different context be an effective solution.

Comment: I've heard it with test rabbits.  You can do it with faulty glue and bridges if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$10$ slaves can do it in $5$ hours. The key is that $2^{10} = 1024 > 1000$.

For a solution, see a hint:

> Work in binary.

For more details,

> Number the casks and label the slaves according to places in binary; the slaves sample a cask according to whether there is a $0$ or $1$ at their position. The status of the slaves after $5$ hours determines a number in binary accordingly, with $0$ and $1$ representing dead and alive, respectively. The cask with the corresponding number is poisoned.

Comment: Each slave will have to sample about 500 casks of wine in less than an hour, and in sufficient quantity to die if one of them is poisoned. Result: 10 slaves dead from alcohol poisoning. Now what?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I suppose they'll at least die happy?

Comment: And because of the gap between 1000 and 1024, you can guarantee that at least 2 slaves survive.  Probably best to randomize the numbering so the poisoner can't hope to maximize the number of deaths by choosing the right cask: you may be an unscrupulous king, but surely there's still a cost to losing a slave.

Comment: This is very clever, but I share @HenningMakholm's concern. There are edge cases where it's ambiguous which cask was poisoned.

Comment: @JulesMazur: It's clearly the _intended_ solution -- the fact that the number of casks is just below 2 to the number of slaves is a dead (!) giveaway.

Answer (score 0):

A very uninteresting way. (I THINK) . make $10$ slaves to drink $1000$ glasses resprectively by making different sections . let them start drinking . Assuming they take 1/2hr   for this purpose.  Now do this again by interchanging section of each slave . this can be done $5$ times. Now assume 5 slaves react at $30$ mins and 5 at  $5hrs$ and we know who reacts with what time . But while drinking record the time and name of the person on the cask or on  the paper . The time at which a person died would then be known and as we know the reaction timings then comparing with time on the cask he drank the poisonous glass can be removed out . If time periods are different and if you can make assumptions then assume that somehow you know in what time a person will react. That would make it little bit easy

Comment: In this type of problem, you can usually assume that actions like drinking or changing places are instantaneous. I'm also asking specifically for an answer which would work in an absolute worst-case scenario, if the poison takes 5 hours to act. Also keep in mind that any reaction time *between* 5 hours and 30 minutes is possible.